# url parameter for a generic view

Tags: django, url, url-parameters, django-generic-views

I have a stupid problem about a wrong url...

In the html menu:

```
<a href="/user_app/update_profile?pk={{ user.pk }}">Update my profile</a>
```

In urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^update_profile', login_required(UpdateProfile.as_view())),
)
```

In view.py:

```
class UpdateProfile(UpdateView):
    form_class = UpdateProfileForm
    template_name = "user_app/update_profile.html"

    #add a success message if the form is valid
    def form_valid(self, form):
        messages.success(self.request, "Your profile has been updated.", extra_tags='success')
        return super(UpdateProfile, self).form_valid(form)

    #modifcation: display the user's data given his primary key
    def get_object(self):
        return UserModel.objects.get(pk=self.request.GET.get('pk'))
```

In my template update_profile.html:

```
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Now my problem...
From the menu I click on "Update my profile". The url is "/user_app/update_profile?pk=1". The page is displayed, I can change the data. Now I click on submit to save the modifications. I want the program to stay on the page but it does not, it changes to "/user_app/". And django displays the following error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in arpaso.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^/?$
^auth/?$
^user_app/? ^show_profile
^user_app/? ^update_profile
The current URL, user_app/, didn't match any of these.
```

Why is my url changed on submit?

**Edit: weird error...**

If I use a template context processor to get the current url, I can use the full current url in my template:

```
<form action="{{ current_path }}" method="post">
```

When I display it, I get current_path="/user_app/update_profile?pk=1"

Now, when I submit the form, I am redirected to "/users/admin/" and get an error (I have no such url in my website). Where does this url come from?

Comment: Try removing `action="."` from template.

Comment: Very strange... if I remove the form action, the url after submit is "users/admin/". I don't have such a url in my website!

Comment: Try action="" in the form.

Comment: I get the same problem: I am redirected to /users/admin/. I have no idea where this url comes from...

Comment: Have you defined a `get_absolute_url` on your model?

Comment: I didn't try that function, but I just tried get_success_url and it works :). Problem solved! Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **EDIT: SOLVED!**

I just added get_success_url to my view and now it works :):

```
def get_success_url(self):
    succ_url =  '/user_app/update_profile?pk='+self.request.GET.get('pk')
    return succ_url
```